# Gulp change paths/links in html files after copying to dist directory

Tags: gulp

I created a static website and I use gulp for automation. Now, I copy also my html files to dist directory using `gulp pages` but when I checked that directory and open any html files, stylesheets and all other links are broken due to relative paths. Is there a way to change the paths for the stylesheets and images while copying html to dist directory?

**gulpfile.js**

```
"use strict";

const gulp = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
const htmlmin = require("gulp-htmlmin");
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
const sassPaths = ["./node_modules"];

function style() {
  return gulp
    .src("./app/scss/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass({ includePaths: sassPaths, outputStyle: "compressed" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/dist/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function images() {
  return gulp
    .src("./app/images/**/*")
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("/app/dist/images"));
}

function pages() {
  return gulp
    .src(["./app/**/*html"])
    .pipe(
      htmlmin({
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/dist"));
}

function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "./app"
    }
  });
  gulp.watch("./app/scss/**/*.scss", style, images);
  gulp.watch("./app/**/*.html").on("change", browserSync.reload);
}

exports.style = style;
exports.images = images;
exports.pages = pages;
exports.watch = watch;
```

I want to change the generated files inside dist directory from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/app.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/app.css" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [gulp-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml) or a similar package like [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref).

And then in your html file you would have something like:

```
<!-- build:css ./css/app.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/app.css">
<!-- /build -->
```

that would change your link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/app.css" />`

```
const modifyHTMLlinks = require("gulp-processhtml");  // or try gulp-useref

function pages() {
  return gulp
    .src(["./app/**/*html"])
    .pipe(modifyHTMLlinks())
    .pipe(
      htmlmin({
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./app/dist"));
}
```